# private field vs private static field in abstract class

Tags: java, static, field, abstract-class, private

I am confused about the scope of a `private` field versus a `private static` field of an abstract class. For example, consider the following classes and note the field `validator`,

```
abstract class ValidComponent {
    private static Validator validator = ... //(statement to instantiate new Validator)

    /** 
     *  This method is to be used by subclasses in their factory-methods 
     *  to do some validation logic after instantiation.
     */
    protected void selfValidate() {
        //validation logic
        ...
        validator.validate(this); // <<< This line uses the validator
        ...
    }
}

class ValidUsername extends ValidComponent {

    private @NotEmpty String core;
    private ValidUsername(String unamestr) {
        this.core = unamestr;
    }

    /** This is the factory-method who use selfValidate() */
    public static ValidUsername create(String unamestr) {
        ValidUsername vuname = new ValidUsername(unamestr);
        vuname.selfValidate();
        return vuname;
    }
}

class ValidEmail extends ValidComponent {
    private @Email String core;
    private ValidEmail(String emailstr) {
        this.core = emailstr;
    }

    /** This is the factory-method who use selfValidate() */
    public static ValidEmail create(String emailstr) {
        ValidEmail vemail = new ValidEmail(emailstr);
        vemail.selfValidate();
        return vemail;
    }
}
```

The abstract class `ValidComponent` prepares method `selfValidate()`, in which the `private static` field, `validator`, is used.

The `ValidUsername` and `ValidEmail` are subclasses that illustrate the intention of their base class: the method `selfValidate()` are used in their factory-methods to validate themself.

If my understanding is correct, when `vuname.selfValidate()` and `vemail.selfValidate()` are called, both use the same `Validator` object, i.e. `ValidComponent.validator`.

**But what if I happen to change the modifiers of `validator` from `private static` to only `private`, are `Validor` objects used in `vuname.selfValidate()` and `vemail.selfValidate()` still the same object?**

Comment: `private static` can't be accessed from outside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a private variable,

```
private String name;
```

and its `getter/setter` which are ofcourse `public`.

Now every class has access to getter/setter which in its implementation uses private variable. That's the purpose of private variables, not accessing it **directly** from other classes.

Your case is similar where in private validator is being accessed by `selfValidate()` method. By their signature, `selfValidate()` is accessible to subclasses.

To answer your question about whether validator object will be different in case of non-static or not, then every class that accesses it will create a **new instance** of that object.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not. The `static` keyword means the field belongs to a **class**. It will be a single instance across whole VM. Without the `static` keyword the field belongs to an **object**, so each instance of the ValidComponent or its subclasses will produce new Validator object.

Comment: So, does this mean that an object will inherit private fields of it superclass even if it cannot access them?

Comment: No, but it inherits the selfValidate() method which has an access to that field. Static methods/fields cannot be inherrited, this doesn't make any sense and it has nothing to do with the access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

> are Validor objects used in vuname.selfValidate() and
>   vemail.selfValidate() still the same object?

No, only static data member can be shared whether private or not. Here `private static Validator validator = ...`is a data member of **class** ValidComponent whereas `private Validator validator = ...`is a data member of **object** and can't share with another object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I don't think this is appropriate, to use the same `Validator` for different objects. Your `Valid*` classes don't share the same constraints therefore the same validation errors. Sharing the same object can cause inconsistency.

You can change `private static` to `private`, but your design might be problematic from the outset.

Maybe [factory pattern](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/23/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/) suits you better.

To answer your question

> are still the same object?

No they are not.